# Weird fast fail stack error that seems to depend on number of identical lines of code

Tags: c++, enums, static, unordered-map

I have this function here which works as written:

```
void Material::initializeTextureStringEnumMap() {
    stringEnumMap.emplace("_MainTex", TextureTypes::MainTex);
    stringEnumMap.emplace("_BumpMap", TextureTypes::BumpMap);
    stringEnumMap.emplace("_BumpSpecMap", TextureTypes::BumpSpecMap);
    stringEnumMap.emplace("_DetailsTex", TextureTypes::DetailTex);
    stringEnumMap.emplace("_ShadowTex", TextureTypes::ShadowTex);
    stringEnumMap.emplace("_TranslucencyMap", TextureTypes::TranslucencyMap);
    stringEnumMap.emplace("_DetailAlbedoMap", TextureTypes::DetailAlbedoMap);
    stringEnumMap.emplace("_DetailMask", TextureTypes::DetailMask);
    stringEnumMap.emplace("_DetailNormalMap", TextureTypes::DetailNormalMap);
    stringEnumMap.emplace("_EmissionMap", TextureTypes::EmissionMap);
    stringEnumMap.emplace("_OcclusionMap", TextureTypes::OcclusionMap);
    stringEnumMap.emplace("_ParallaxMap", TextureTypes::ParallaxMap);
    stringEnumMap.emplace("_SpecGlossMap", TextureTypes::SpecGlossMap);
    stringEnumMap.emplace("_MetallicGlossMap", TextureTypes::MetallicGlossMap);
    //stringEnumMap.emplace("_Diffuse", TextureTypes::Diffuse);
}
```

`stringEnumMap` is a static `unordered_map` `string` to `enum`, if it's not clear from the code.

Now, if you uncomment that last line, the program will fail during runtime, throwing error in `gs_report.c` at line 220:

```
if (IsProcessorFeaturePresent(PF_FASTFAIL_AVAILABLE))
        {
            __fastfail(FAST_FAIL_STACK_COOKIE_CHECK_FAILURE);
        }
```

I don't understand why this happens. I read a file that has, among other things, strings in it. I need to apply appropriate enum to the object depending on the string. That's why I created `static unordered_map` that connects the two.

Any ideas?

Comment: `FAST_FAIL_STACK_COOKIE_CHECK_FAILURE` sounds to me like you busted your stack. Check the call stack at the point of failure. If it isn't too large, you probably have undefined behavior in an unrelated part of your code.

Comment: Can me make a reproducible [mcve]?

Comment: After a quick Google search, [it looks like you have a buffer overrun](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8dbf701c.aspx) somewhere that threatens the return address of a function.

Comment: Okay, update time, the error sometimes appear, sometimes doesn't, with no code change. Is it possible that VS2017 is doing something weird and spazing out every now and then?

Comment: Sounds like another symptom of undefined behavior in your code.

Comment: @Karlovsky120 This problem is likely a symptom of an unrelated problem elsewhere in your code. Since it looks like you may be performing static initialization, you may be experiencing a problem related to static initialization order (but that's just a wild guess). Make sure non of your `static` members and globals depend on any other `static` member of global from other translation units.

Comment: If that function is being called during static initialization, it’s possible that the map hasn’t been constructed yet.

Comment: The enum in question, Diffuse was the last item in it, and it had a comma after it. VS didn't complain about it, but I suspect it might have had something to do with the error.